# Textfield can't delete after page change in Pageview?

Tags: flutter

Very simple code like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: PageView(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
              ],
            ),
            Center(child: Text("2")),
            Center(child: Text("3")),
            Center(child: Text("4")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Input something on the textfield, then go to the next page, then back. Can't delete anything now, but can input? If click another textfield and then click back, everything is back to normal.
[image: Screen recording gif]

Comment: if you use ```navigator.push``` the content inside textfield will still be there

Comment: @uyhaW, then what we need to use?

Answer (score 0):

you can clear your controller after clicking back from second screen to first screen, try below code

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                new SecondScreen())).then((res) {
      yourControllerTextField.clear();
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
```

Comment: It's in PageView, not page to page.

Comment: Hi @395coder, I am sorry for my late reply. I think you can use property onPageChanged inside PageView and then check it when  controllerTextfield.text is not null or "", also index==0 => clear the controller textfield